# Using PHP, I want to split a string after a certain number of words

Tags: php, explode

I tried a few functions such as `str_split()`, `chop()`, and `explode()`. But they don't quite do what I want.

For example:
`$str = "it was the best of times it was the worst of times";`
The result I was looking for was to segment the `$str` after 5 words.
So it would look like:
`$new_str = "it was the best of";`

Thank You.

Comment: `explode()` by space and take the first 5 elements of the resulting array. Please post what you tried and where it fails

Comment: So, you're suggesting the following? 
<?
$str = "it was the best of times it was the worst of times";
$new_str = explode(" ", $str);
echo "$new_str[0] ";
echo "$new_str[1] ";
echo "$new_str[2] ";
echo "$new_str[3] ";
echo "$new_str[4] ";
?>

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode` to turn string into an array. Then use `array_splice` function with an *offset* of *5* in order take only first five words. Finally `join` them together with *a space*.

```php
$str = "it was the best of times it was the worst of times";
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
array_splice($arr, 5);
$new_str = join(' ', $arr);
echo $new_str;
```

*Prints:* `it was the best of`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short and easy way to do it:

```
<?php
  $sentence = "I am a very nice sentence, look at me, so many words ooh!";
  $wordsToSave = 5; //how many words you want to save
  $shortSentence = array_slice(explode(" ", $sentence), 0, $wordsToSave); //make an array out of the sentence's words and save the first ones
  $sentence = implode(" ", $shortSentence); //make a string out of that array
  echo $sentence;
?>
```

The output, after saving only 5 words from that:

```
I am a very nice
```